# Unit test function of component in reactjs using karma and Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, karma-jasmine

I have one reactjs component   and there is one function inside that component. I want to write unit test case for that. Below is my sample unit test case. function name is  getNewGroupName

```
describe("CreateGroupName component", () => {

      it("Correct Copy name should be generated for first copy", () => {
          component = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument( < CreateGroupName reactor = {
              reactor
            } > < /CreateGroupName>);

            expect(component.getNewGroupName("SampleGroupName")).tobe("SampleGroupName - Copy(1)")
          });

      });
```

But when I am running unit test cases I am getting below error

TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'e.getNewGroupName("SampleGroupName")')

After looking into the object using the debugger I am able to see only below property for this object.

[image]

I also tried writing above test using enzyme library. But Both are giving me same object in the result.

```
 it("Correct Copy name should be generated for first copy", () => {
            const wrapper = enzyme.mount(<CreateGroupName reactor={reactor}></CreateGroupName>);
            const inst = wrapper.instance();
            expect(inst.getNewGroupName('SampleGroupName')).toBe("SampleGroupName - Copy(1)");
        });
```

Here is my component

[image]

stack trace is as below

```
"TypeError: t.getNewGroupName is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/base/app/spec/webpack.loader.js:96:18873)
    at attemptSync (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1886:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1874:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1859:10)
    at Spec.queueRunnerFactory (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:697:35)
    at Spec.execute (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:359:10)
    at Object.fn (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:2479:37)
    at attemptAsync (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1916:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1871:9)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1898:16"
```

Comment: What does the CreateGroupName component look like?  This usually happens when it's not returning something properly.

Comment: What about `.toBe()` instead of `.tobe()`?

Comment: i corrected this but still it is not working

Comment: Where is `e.getNewGroupName("SampleGroupName")` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument() renders a DOM node representing the output of your component after it renders. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#renderintodocument

It looks like you're attempting to call getNewGroupName() which is a function on your React component, not a method on the rendered DOM node.

Comment: Is there any way to test functions of the component? Or is that not possible

Comment: Take a look at Jest (https://facebook.github.io/jest/) to helping unit test React components. Also look at Enzyme (http://airbnb.io/enzyme/) for help to render a component and then assert against the rendered result. You can then use renderedresult.instance().yourfunction() to call methods on your component. Take a look here : https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/208

Comment: If you check my second sample of the unit test case, I am doing the same thing and it is failing